# Wordpress images borders on Search Bar

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

Being punched in the brain by php strings again! I need to have an image border on either side of the search bar in twentyeleven Wordpress (I have added a child theme so don't worry)

Here is my attempt

```
<?php echo '<img src="/wp/images/search-side.png" />' . 'get_search_form()' . '<img src="/wp/images/search-side.png" />'; ?>
```

It is not working

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting the form method as text:

```
<?php echo '<img src="/wp/images/search-side.png" />' . get_search_form() . '<img src="/wp/images/search-side.png" />'; ?>
```

+ if the images do not display, check if the path is right.

Comment: I see the images but the php code is showing on the screen instead of the actual text field

Comment: Try the code as I posted it, meaning, get_search_form() **w/out** the `'`

Comment: Would you know how to make them stay eitherside of the seach box? They appear elsewhere on the screen and I have wrapped a div (style = relative) round the entire string and the search bar vanishes

Comment: Look more inside `get_search_form`. You can probably add class to it that controls the images.

Comment: I sorted it thanks. Looked in the search php file and did it in there. Thanks for your help